# Auto complete input field mandatory in form

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms

I have one field and i want to make it as mandatory on form submit.

here is the code:

```
    <div class="form-group">
  <form name="addressform">
        <span><small><strong> choose Location : </small></strong></span>

        <div>
            <input type="text" name="address" id="LocationAutocomplete" class="form-control" ng-autocomplete="result1"   ng-model="addressTemp" required/>
</form>
            <div ng-show="showMap">
                <div id="location_map_canvas" style="width:100%;height:200px"> </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" ng-submit value="create" ng-disabled="frm.$invalid" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" ng-click="createt()">
                  </div>
```

Comment: what about required attribute?

Comment: Thanks and i used that too @user7326764  no use

Comment: First put this code into "form" tag, then use ng-required="true"

Comment: Would you mind creating a fiddle? It should do the trick, may be your form has novalidate attribute then it will be ignored, for instance

Comment: Can you please explain more on what 1. is currently happening (what is not working) and 2. what you expect to happen?

Comment: user must entry that field,if forgot to entry when user click on submit that form will not create @chrki

Comment: Thanks.i don't have a idea to create a fiddle @user7326764

Comment: Do you want to prevent the user to submit the form is input is missing or just add a default value for that input?

Comment: can you brief me bit more @ManuelObregozo

Comment: You have two alternatives in Here: 1) Autocomple will work as a default value, it means you will have always a value for that input.
2) Prevent the user to submit the form if a selected input has no value in it.

Comment: yes second one  @ManuelObregozo

Comment: Check the answer that I just posted

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131601/discussion-between-manuel-obregozo-and-shiva).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this working demo :**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.create = function() {
      console.log("submitting..");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <form name="addressform" ng-submit="addressform.$valid && create()" novalidate>
        <span ng-show="submitted == true && addressform.address.$error.required">Required field.</span>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="address" id="LocationAutocomplete" class="form-control" ng-autocomplete="result1" ng-model="addressTemp" required/>
        </div>
    <div class="form-group">
       <input type="submit" value="create" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" ng-click="submitted = true">
    </div>
 </form>
</div>
```

Comment: when i use same thing in plunker ,error message showing by defaultly @Roht Jindal

Comment: But here it is working fine you can check the `code snippet`. It is working as per your expectations.

Comment: thnks.Yes it is working here.but used same thing in page not working there and i copied to plunker and tested there also not working

Comment: It is working fine in plnkr also http://plnkr.co/edit/rIQV2KteputkP1u8edR4?p=preview please check properly.

Comment: Thanks @Rohith Jindal not working in my code.Unable to understand whats wrong in my code bro

Comment: But my answer is correct as per your expectation i also provided demo to you in `fiddle` and `plnkr` both. If you think it is suitable please mark it as a correct so that it will be useful for others also.

Comment: help me to out this prob

Answer (score 0):

`<input name="movie" type="text" required />`

This is how you would make an input text field required.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`ngRequired`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRequired)

```
<input type="text" id="LocationAutocomplete" class="form-control" ng-autocomplete="result1" ng-model="addressTemp" ng-required="required"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-required="true"` as follows:

```
<input type="text" id="LocationAutocomplete" class="form-control" ng-autocomplete="result1" ng-model="addressTemp" ng-required="true" name="input"/>

<input type="submit" ng-disabled="myform.input.$error.required">Submit</input>
```

Comment: what you exactly want to do?

Comment: user must entry that field,if forgot to entry when user click on submit that form will not create @Sai

Comment: You can disable the submit button, if not entered.

Answer (score 0):

use angularjs form validation
 https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController  with ng-message and (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages/directive/ngMessages)

if you want in submit(ng-submit="checkAndSave")..
do in controller..

```
$scope.checkAndSave = function(){

// validations code if ok do save else throw whatever you want
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the form tag, and name the form and all of your inputs

```
<form name="form" ng-submit="submitform()">
    <input name="addres" type="text" id="LocationAutocomplete" class="form-control" ng-model="addressTemp" required/>

    <button type="submit" ng-disabled="form.$invalid"> Submit </button>
</form>
```

With this, you will have the Submit button disabled if the input is Invalid.
since it has the required attribute, if the input is blank it will appear as invalid.

Find this working sample:
https://plnkr.co/edit/F0Id7HDm9pkrCTTG42U5?p=preview

Comment: What is the issue then?

Comment: without entering any thing in that field am able to submit the form @Manuel Obregozo

Comment: did you add the recommendations that we made in your code? if yes, could you please update your question's code.